# Word choose between か and のか

Tags: particles, particle-か

I have a question about the following sentence:

> お母さんが、八百屋で長いこと、**何を買うか**決まらず迷っています。

Is it possible to replace "か" with "のか" without misunderstanding in this sentence? Namely,

> お母さんが、八百屋で長いこと、**何を買うのか**決まらず迷っています。

Answer (score 5):

This の is called "explanatory-no". Its basic role is to provide an explanation for the current background context. When it's used with the question marker か, のか seeks clarification or explanation for the current context.

- [Explanatory のだ （んだ）](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/)
- [Question Markers: か and の](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/question-markers/)
- [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- [How is the "のです" working here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3349/5010)

As described in the second link, の can form a casual question even without か, although in this case か is required since it's in an [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010).

That said, in this specific case, I think both sentences are almost completely interchangeable, with or without の. Maybe the latter sounds slightly more emphatic or emotional.

On the other hand, の is almost mandatory in the following context:

> お母さんは八百屋で30分も買い物をしていた。何を買った**の**か知りたい。

This is a typical case where の is used to seek clarification.