# Understanding これで体験版ってんだから

Tags: grammar, particles

> 『はー……すっごいなぁ、最近のゲームって。これ**で**体験版**ってんだから**、こりゃ製品版出たら買うしかないなあ』

How should I understand the bold で grammatically? I understand the これで as conveying a nuance of “although the the game is well designed”. But I am not sure if で can mean “although”, which can’t be found in any dictionary I know.

And how is 体験版ってんだから different from 体験版だから?

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to find an English equivalent of「で」here. I'd say it's similar to "with". これで："with this". But more natural English renditions would be  "in this shape", "under these circumstances", etc.

A similar usage is 私でよければ…: "If I am fine..." "If you are fine with me" This phrase can be used in many ways.

「ってんだから」：「というのだから」See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14400/30454)

> はー……すっごいなぁ、最近のゲームって。これで体験版ってんだから、こりゃ製品版出たら買うしかないなあ

My rendition:

> Wow, that's amazing! (Can't believe) recent games. If something like that is a demo, I will really have to buy the public release version when it comes out.

Comment: +1, but I'd rather say "in this shape", "under these circumstances" or so.

Comment: @brokenlaptop Thank you! Fixed.

Comment: @brokenlaptop  Thank you both. As for 「というのだから」, I read that link before I asked the question. But I don't feel the 「というのだから」means "since they say" in my sentence. Is it natural to say just 体験版だから? Is the というの just for emphasis?

Comment: @chinoalpha "they say" is, reasonably versatile, but merely one of many ways to translate という.  The word is much more neutral, compared to "literally that..." or quotation marks themselves.