# comparison between のですから and んだから

Tags: grammar

Recently I read though the [article](https://www.jpf.go.jp/j/project/japanese/teach/tsushin/grammar/201009.html) addressing the question  [(んだから vs んだ)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-vs-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-vs-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0) where it explains the usage of のだから as:

> １）話し手も聞き手も知っている事柄に用いられ、「聞き手（あなた）も知ってはいるが、その認識が十分でない」ことを知らせようとする話し手の強い気持ちが入る。
>
> ２）後件には、「そういうことだから、～たい、～はずだ、～ほうがいい、～てください」などの、話し手の判断や意志、願望、働きかけなどの表現が来ることが多い。

However, when the author explained the provided exercise,

```
   Ａ：同窓会の仕事頼まれちゃって。
　 Ｂ：大変なの？
　 Ａ：うん。
　 Ｂ：でも、（ａ．引き受けたから　ｂ．引き受けたんだから）、しっかりやりなさいね。
```

she wrote such sentence

> ＢはＡが同窓会の仕事を頼まれたことを知り、その事実（事情）を踏まえて、頑張るように励ましている**のですから**、ｂ「引き受けたんだから」が適切になります。

I thought this bold のですから is merely a formal version of んだから at once. But after deeper thinking, I found the sentence following のですから is not the writer's  intent, wish, or request. Rather, it is an objective description. Thus, I draw the conclusion that the usage of のですから is different than listed above.

How should I use のですから if it is not as simply as a formal version of んだから?

(By the phrase formal version I mean the corresponding 丁寧語.)

Comment: The thing following is やり**なさい**....

Comment: I think an objective description is a firmly believed decision or opinion. In other words, It's a strong version of the case ～ほうがいい.

Answer (score 1):

> でも、引き受けたんだからしっかりやりなさいね

This is not an objective description. やりなさい is a form of command. This is the same if you convert it into 丁寧語.

> でも、引き受けたのですから、しっかりやって下さい

*EDIT*: Same thing with `頑張るように励ましているのですから`。

> 励ましているのですからｂが適切になります
>   励ましているんだからｂが適切だ

Both have the same meaning.

Comment: I mean the のですから in "ＢはＡが同窓会の仕事を頼まれたことを知り、その事実（事情）を踏まえて、頑張るように励ましている　のですから　、ｂ「引き受けたんだから」が適切になります"

Comment: @NoNames: Added edit. HTH