# What does のですが mean in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, formal-nouns, conjunctions

> 焼き鳥屋さんで集まった**のですが**、とても楽しい、かつ有意義な時間を過ごしました。

Comment: This sentence is strange besides the point asked. It should be `とても楽しく、かつ`.

Answer (score 21):

～のですが (or ～のですけれども, or ～んだけど, or any of a number of variants) is often used in this way to "set the stage" and provide a context for a succeeding clause or sentence. Here, the purpose of ～のですが is to mark information that will help the listener understand the second half of the sentence. As such, the が here is best translated into English as "and", not "but".

This is one of the many [uses of ～のだ to provide supporting information](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/what-connotation-does-add/1863#1863) for other statements.