# Use of が in this sentence

Tags: particle-が

What’s the pattern in the following use of が?

> 友達と海に行ってバーベキューをしたんですが、楽しかったですよ。

I asked my teacher and she said it was similar to ので to state a cause and effect.

Comment: Possibly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/what-does-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8c-mean-in-the-following-sentence

Comment: And https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010