# Different meanings of ですが

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I have started reading 「魔女の宅急便」, and I found a sentence I quite understand, but for the exact meaning of 「ですが」:

> キキのばあいも、十歳の中ごろ、魔女になる決心をしたの**ですが**、そのあとすぐ、コキリさんの持っている魔法を習いはじめました

As far as I know, 「ですが」 means something like "but", and on [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C) is listed as such; as far as I understand, [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C) agrees.

With that meaning, I would translate the sentence something like "Kiki too, when she was ten years old, decided to become a witch, **but** immediately after that she started to learn the magic Kokiri [Kiki's mother] knew" (literally, "have", but in English maybe "know" is a better fit).

Now, in the book girls deciding if they will be witches when they are 10 years old, and if so starting training, is the norm; my doubt is that if I were to write the same sentence in English, I'd write something on the line of "she decide to become a witch, **so** immediately after", since it's a quite logical consequence of her decision. I don't understand why 「ですが」 is used, since if I were to translate it "but" in English it would give a meaning of something unexpected, in some way contrary to the premise (e.g., "she decided **not** to become a which, but she started training all the same": in this case, the training would not be the logical consequence of her choice).

So, I was wondering what's the implication and/or reason to use 「ですが」 in this sentence.

Comment: I believe this thread answers your question:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/what-does-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C-mean-in-the-following-sentence