# What additional meaning that なんだ add to the sentence

Tags: grammar

A. 彼は大学生ですよ 
B. 彼は大学生なんだよ 
What difference that なんだ makes in this sentence?

For A, I understand it well as "He is a college student!" 
For B, eventhough i have read much article written about なんだ... I still cannot understand it.

I notice that there are な+んだ or 何だ. 
I feel that it was the な のだ, but i still wasn't sure as to how it changes the meaning of sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What connotation does なんだ add?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/what-connotation-does-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0-add)

Comment: @blavius Thanks for pointing out the link. After reading it, i get to a conclusion that なんだ sentence means "Hey, It turns out that he is a college student!". The なんだ means "the case is that..." Is my understanding correct ? If it is, i will then delete this post :)

Comment: The meaning of のだ depends on context.  We can't be sure about how it's used without a more specific question.

Comment: @snail plane,there was no more context given. There is someone answering the B question though. "そう なんだ"

Answer (score 2):

In this case, なんだ is used for emphasis. For example, you can use it if you are answering someone's question and you are confident in your answer. Let's say for example that someone asked you if so-and-so is a student, and the questioner isn't certain (doubting) that they are a student, you can say はい, せいとなんだ. (Yes, he/she **is in fact** a student)