# Meaning of なんやけどな

Tags: meaning, expressions, manga, kansai-ben

I was translating a manga chapter and found this line:

> 蛍なんやけどな今行方不明になっててな

What's the meaning of なんやけどな?

Comment: 「なんだけどな」だったらわかるでしょうか？

Comment: Does this answer your question?　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62558/9831

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58140/45489

Answer (score 1):

「なんやけど」means 「なんだけど」in the Kansai dialect, mostly spoken in the Kansai region. This sentence roughly means "About the fireflies, they're lost."

Answer (score 0):

Flat meaning of "なんやけどな" in your case is something like "as for." If this phrase is used at the front, the speaker often implies "I'm going to tell you something you do not anticipate," for both good and bad outcomes.