# What is 〜んだ and how is it used?

Tags: conjugations

I was listening to a playlist of songs today and I heard the line

> 「…目を開け弱さをかき消すんだ」

What exactly is 〜んだ and when/how is it used?

Comment: FWIW, 〜のだ is a bit hard to explain in totality due to all the different ways it can be used/interpreted. The 大辞林 entry is probably a reasonable place to start, though: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-596938

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「んだ」 is a colloquial pronunciation of 「のだ」.

In this context, 「んだ」, together with the preceding verb, expresses a firm request or even a demand or imperative.

**"Open up your eyes and get rid of your weakness!"**

We do not use 「んだ」 this way on a daily basis; At least many of do not.  It is most often used by the teacher or leader types who need to give advice and cheer people on.