# Questions about の→ん contraction, でござる→でございます shift

Tags: grammar, words, etymology, contractions, archaic-language

**【原文】*Original version***

各これらの語の特徴はいつからなの？何時代ですの？

第一、「のです」と「なのです」を書いて「んです」と「なんです」を書かなかったことはいつからなの？

第に、「でござる」を書いて「でございます」を書かなかったこともいつからなの？

私の日本語がよくないですと、すみません！

---

**Edited version**

I have two questions about the expressions in Japanese:

1. When were the expressions "のです" and "なのです" replaced by "んです" and "なんです" respectively?

Similarly,

2. When was the expression "でござる" replaced by "でございます"?

In addition to the questions, I'd like to know the characteristic and the usage of each expression.

ーーーー
**【編集後】**

日本語の言い回しに関して２つ質問があります。

（１）「んです」「なんです」という言い回しは、いつから「のです」「なのです」に各々取って代わったのですか。

同様に、
（２）「でございます」という言い回しは、いつから「でござる」に取って代わったのですか。

また、各々の表現の特徴あるいは使い方などもわかったら教えてください。

Comment: この編集が正しいかどうかやや疑問に思います。「そもそも取って代わってない」という話になるので。

Comment: @user4092 If you have some information that deserves the answer to the original question, I recommend you to answer the question along with showing how you interpreted the original question.
If I had an informative answer to it, I did like that. But to my regret, I didn't have any answer to the difficult question and I also wanted to know the answer, so I dared to arrange the original answer poorly as the edited version. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what it's saying. Given that your interpretation is the case, my answer is "they have not been replaced to begin with".

Comment: His translation of my awful Japanese is spot on actually. Apologies if my question is stupid or makes no sense btw.

Answer (score -1):

**Q1:** **When were the expressions** **"のです" and "なのです"** **replaced by "んです" and "なんです" respectively?**

**A1**:

[1] how difference use way

**[のです、 んです] vs [なのです、なんです]**

(1) [のです、んです]

**1. verb+の(ん)です**

**2. い adjective+の(ん)です**

(2) [なのです、なんです ]

**1. noun+な(attributive だ)+の(ん)です**

**2. な adjective+な(attributive だ)+の(ん)です**

Reference

1. [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-)～んです-～のだ

---

**Q2**:**When was the expression "でござる" replaced by "でございます"?**

**A2:**:**でございます used when is you should speak more formal and polite でござる to your higher**

and

"「ござる」は本来「御座有(ござあ)る」で尊敬語でした。

後に丁寧語に使われるようになりました。"

Source and detail

1. https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11120077396

Comment: Every time you edit your post, it bumps the question to the top of the list of active questions so people can review your changes.  You've edited your post 25 times in the last day; this is a very large number of edits.  Please consider trying to make *fewer, more substantial* edits.

Comment: @Dohak 質問は、「 **いつから/いつの時代から** 、『のです』『なのです』『でござる』と書くのをやめて、『んです』『なんです』『でございます』と書き始めたのですか？」って聞いてると思うんです。でも、その答えを見つけるのはちょっと難しそうです。「のです」「なのです」は、今も使いますから。「でござる」は、これが参考になるかも ⇒ [デジタル大辞泉「ござる」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/78449/meaning/m0u/) 一番下、`[補説]室町時代から江戸時代までは広く用いられたが、・・・江戸時代に入ると「まする」「ます」を伴う形がしだいに一般化し…`

Comment: @Chocolate 私は、**「いつ、AがBに交われるの?」**のと、**「いつからAがBに交われたの?」**二つで悩んでいました。英語が苦手で質問の理解ができませんでした。Advice, ありがとうございます。