# What's the difference between じゃない and じゃないんだ?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I was learning how to conjugate the state-of-being and I didn't see じゃないんだ in the conjugation chart...I often hear people use it in movies and dramas... is it part of the conjugation for the state-of-being or part of some other conjugation? Sorry if my question is sort of confusing.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-～んです-～のだ-etc