# Use of の with かもしれない

Tags: grammar, particle-の, no-da

> 北海道の海岸に向かう途中で、川に入ってしまった**の**かもしれません。
>   They might have ended up entering the river en route to the Hokkaido coast.

What is の (in bold) doing in this sentence? It was my understanding that かもしれない came straight after the predicate.

My guess is that this is the so-called 'explanatory の' rather than a nominaliser. Please can you confirm or correct my thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a typical example of [explanatory-の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010). Looking at the [source](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011292341000/k10011292341000.html), we can see this sentence is trying to explain *why* the アザラシ was found in the mountain.

> - 川に入ってしまいました。
>     The animal ended up entering the river.
> - 川に入ってしまったのです。
>     It is that the animal ended up entering the river.
> - 川に入ってしまったかもしれません。
>     The animal may have ended up entering the river.
> - 川に入ってしまったのかもしれません。
>     It may be that the animal ended up entering the river.