# How to understand 「僕は誰より彼女が好きなんだ。」

Tags: particle-より, explanatory-の

I don't understand 「僕は誰より彼女が好きなんだ。」. I guess 好きなんだ means love, but なん means not. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

なん does not mean "not". This (な)ん is something called "explanatory-の". You can learn about it in the following articles.

- [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- [Explanatory のだ （んだ）](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/)

より is a particle to mark a comparison target. So the sentence is the same as 僕は誰より彼女が好きだ but with an added nuance. Perhaps the person is trying to convince someone. The translation would be "I love her more than anybody (else)."

Comment: @macraf If I wrote something misleading, please feel free to correct it :)

Comment: But I wasn't sure. Actually one might claim it actually *is* a negation as in ナンセンス :)

Comment: Ah, I was not thinking of "non-" at all :D