# Can you nominalize a verb and then use it again as verb by combining with です?

Tags: nominalization

I have come across a sentence which I do not know if I understand correctly.

> すべて の コイン を もらえる の です か？

I know that in this sentence the speaker asks if he wins/receives all of the coins, but I am not sure if I understand the structure and logic of it.

So far I know the particle "の" as a marker of possession or like the genitive like in the beginning of the sentence ("all of the coins"). But I did not understand why there is another "の" before "です か". I found out that "の" is also used to nominalize a verb. In this case this seems to be "もらえる の". But in use with "です" I think it is again used as verb. I have doubts if my interpretation is correct, because this seems to be too complicated.

Comment: That の has a different usage. It is called the explanatory の. There's a lot about it on this site. Try this link for starters: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a0-etc

Comment: This answers my question, so I think the translation is more appropriate as "so this means I win all of the coins." Thank you!

Comment: @MaximilianBrtk Aside from your example, you can actually use の + です how you said i.e. この山が今日届いたのです "The pile here _is ones_ we received today."

Comment: Explanatory の also contracts to ん a lot, especially in speech. So watch out for that, too.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot for your answers! (: