# Confirming someones plans?

Tags: words

In Pimsler 2 they use the and expression something like えくん to confirm someones actions. Can someone help me find this word in a dictionary, or tell me what form it comes from.

> 飛行機{ひこうき}で　えくん　ですね。
>   You are going by plane, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect you are mishearing `いく` as `えく`。Remember that `え` sounds like the `e` at the beginning of `edge`, whereas `い` is like the `y` in `sleepy`.

The word you want is [行く](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F), which means `to go` (among other things). The `ん` is a contraction of `の`, which you can read more about [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-etc), or many other places online with a quick Google search.