# I need some help with んです/ので/ん

Tags: grammar, contractions, giving-and-receiving

I was studyng from a book and I can't answer this question (and I don`t have the answers) the question is:
**普通の言い方に直すとどうなりますか。**

1. 私に**予約してくれんか。**

   a)予約してくれないのですか。 b)予約してくれるのですか。 c)予約してくれませんか。

To me all of the answers are the same :(

Comment: Does the original sentence really say **私に**予約してくれんか ?

Answer (score 2):

The ん in 予約してくれ**ん**か is a contracted form of ない. Thus, the sentence is the same as 私に予約してくれ**ない**か. The polite version of this sentence is 私に予約してくれませんか, so I think the answer is **c)**. (I hesitate to call the polite form 普通の言い方, though...)

The other options contain [explanatory-の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010), but it is not included in the original sentence. 予約してくれないのですか means "(Does that mean) you aren't going to make a reservation for me? (That's disappointing!)". 予約してくれるのですか means "(Does that mean) you are going to make a reservation for me?" These are not simple requests.

To distinguish the two types of ん:

- ん after the "pre-nai" form of a verb is a contraction of ない.

  > 食べない → 食べん
  >   要らない → 要らん
- ん after the dictionary form (or more precisely, the attributive form) of a verb is a contraction of の.

  > 食べたのだ → 食べたんだ
  >   要るのです → 要るんです