# What's the meaning of 通じづらい, and how was it conjugated?

Tags: grammar, words, etymology, sentence

I was wondering what the meaning of 通じづらい is, and how it was conjugated.

I know づらい means "difficult" or "hard to" but I can't find the exact meaning of 通じ.

Here is the sentence. The context is that they are talking about how a person didn't use their phone. Someone remarks:

> 携帯あんだろ？ 通じづらいんだよ。

Please explain how this was conjugated.

Comment: Please be sure - as much as is possible - to spend time on writing your questions for clarity. They should be in full sentences, with proper grammar, and without slangy abbreviations (e.g. "idk"), so they are as useful and clear as possible, to as many people as possible. I've edited your question on this occasion to do this! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different elements, so I'll try to break them down for you.

The first sentence

> 携帯あんだろ ？

is a very casual/colloquial way of saying

> 携帯（が）あるんだろう？

In other words, they are asking (semi-rhetorically) whether they have their phone.

As for their second sentence,  通じる is a verb which can mean 'communicate' or 'get through' (amongst others), which suits this context well.

づらい (as you note) is a suffix that means "hard to" or "difficult to". It is appended to the "base" of the verb (more formally, the 連用形 of the verb); for 通じる, the 連用形 is 通じ. So, here, you get a meaning of 'hard to communicate' or 'hard to get through'.

The んだ is adding emphasis (see [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-etc)), and the よ is further strengthening the statement by making it exclamatory.

From what you've said as context, therefore, it sounds like the character speaking is a bit irritated that they weren't able to get through to the other person before, and is scolding them a bit. I'd translate both sentences into natural English as something like:

> You have your mobile phone, don't you? You're so hard to get hold of.