# What does the last の in "おどるのはたのしいのです。" mean/do?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-の

I'm having trouble understanding the grammar of this sentence:

> おどるのはたのしい**の**です。

I understand it means, "Its fun to dance," but I'm struggling to understand why **の** is placed here:
おどるのはたのしい**の**です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something called an explanatory-の.

- [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- [Wasabi: Explanatory のだ (んだ)](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/)

So the last の turns "It's fun to dance" into "It's that it's fun to dance". This の is a kind of a nominalizer that wraps everything before it and forms a noun clause.

- 楽しい。
  Fun.
- 踊るのは楽しい。
  Dancing is fun.
- [踊るのは楽しい**の**]
  [**that** dancing is fun]
- [踊るのは楽しい**の**]です。
  (It) is [**that** dancing is fun].

Note that you need some context for this sentence to make sense. For example, when the listener is wondering why you're dancing, you can say this to explain the reason.