# What happens if なの is used, but not at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 大学から歩いてニ十分ぐらいの所に適当**なの**を見つけた。

What does it mean when なの is used in a sentence like the one above? The を that comes after it is really throwing me off.

I came across [a similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/what-exactly-is-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE-nano) on here but all the examples and explanations relate to なの being used as a way to *end a sentence*. What confuses me the most is なの in the sentence I came across isn't being used to end it. Should I just apply the answers provided in the link I found to this sentence or is there something more to it?

Edit: I was asked to provide more context to the sentence above, so here's the whole sentence:

> キャンパスの近くには,安くていいアパー卜がなくて、結局、大学から歩いてニ十分ぐらいの所に適当なのを見つけた。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not なの but adj-な + の

You might remember this construct from your (very) early Japanese lessons:

> 赤いのをください
>
> *Please give me the red **one**.*

This is the same, except it's with a 'na-adjective'.

> [簡単]{かんたん}なのをください
>
> *Please give me an easy one.*

Hence, 適当なのを見つけた。 means *'I found a suitable one.'*

'In a place twenty minutes' walk away from the university, I found a suitable one.' We need more context to know what 'one' refers to here.

Comment: @Korclus: So memorizing as "の = one" (i.e. a super versatile pronoun) will be helpful.

Comment: I edited my post to include the whole sentence. If I understand the sentence correctly, I believe the 'one' thing in question is an apartment.

Comment: @Korclus: Yes, a 安くていいアパー卜 to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

The を still has the same meaning: it marks the direct object.  Are you comfortable the のを？Probably would help to think of it as the same thing.

既に読んだのを買っちゃいました。
(I bought one I had already read).

The sentence above is saying they found a 適当な所.  を is still necessary to mark the direct object. Think of the の as connecting a な adjective and を.  Does that help?