# What does 嫌いなの (kirainano) mean

Tags: explanatory-の

I know that kirai means to dislike or hate. And I know that nano can be used as a question marker at the end of a sentence. But the context of where I saw kirainano didn’t seem like it was a question. Is nano just a more casual way of saying desu?

Comment: The の here is simply the 代名詞, and can be replaced with こと. Just like 嫌いな人(The disliked person)、嫌いな場所(the disliked place), 嫌いなの simply means the "the disliked thing/the disliked one." It does not have to be a question at all, although it could.

Answer (score 1):

"なの" can be used as either a question marker or an explanatory marker depending on intonation. Think of reading it as "嫌いなの？" versus "嫌いなの".  In this case, the context tells you that it means the latter.

If you want to learn more about なの, check out this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/516/45675) and keep in mind that 嫌い is, sneakily, a な-adjective so the な must be linked to it and の itself is an explanatory-の, which is described in more detail in this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5399/45675).

So, the speaker is explaining that they dislike the implied subject, which would be a response to an inquiry such like:

> なぜそれを捨ててる**の**ですか？ **(Explain)** why are you throwing that away?
>
> 嫌いな**の**。 **(Because)** I hate it.

Also, a super casual way of using です is to not use it at all. More formally this sentence would be 嫌いなのです or 嫌いなんです.

Comment: Even 嫌いなの？ is a shorter and less formal version of 嫌いなのですか or 嫌いなんですか with an explanatory marker の, and it also has a “super casual” version in 嫌い？.

Answer (score 0):

嫌いなの when answering someone is casual/informal feminine, childish, or cute way to say you dislike something. Children (boys/girls) will use it, women will use it. Depends on how it is said whether it is straight feminine usage, or cute, or childish.